# Render label names instead of integer fields in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

As part of my models, I have an IntergerField "choices".

These choices have been labelled. (Label 1 = Straw, Label 2 = Yellow...)

However, the HTML renders the integer rather than the actual labels.

What do I need to do return the labels and not the field's interger?

Is it somethng I need to do in views? Or do I address it directly in the html file?

Code below:

**Models**

```
CHOICE1=(
    ('',''),
    (1,'Straw'),
    (2,'Yellow'),
)

class Model1(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Choice_A = models.IntegerField(choices=Choice1,default=0)
```

**Views**

```
def account(request):
    review_list = Model1.objects.all
    return render(request,"main/account.html", {'review_list':review_list})
```

**HTML**

```
<h6>Champagnes</h6>
{% for Model1 in review_list%}
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered ">
    {% if Model1.user == user%}
    <tr>
        <th>Text</th><th>{{Model1.Choice_A }}</th>
    </tr>
{%endif%}
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the following in your template:

`{{ Model1.get_Choice_A_display }}`

It will render the string instead of the integer

Answer (score 2):

You do this with the [**`.get_fieldname_display(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display), so here `get_Choice_A_display`:

```
<th>Text</th><th>{{Model1.get_Choice_A_display }}</th>
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `choice_a` instead of <s>`Choice_A`</s>.